# Azure AppService Autoscale based on EventHubs incoming messages

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-app-service-plans

I have a .Net app hosted as a Azure App Service (a webjob), that reads from one Event Hub and does some actions on those messages. This app is not CPU or Memory bound, instead I want to base the scaling on the amount of incoming messages to the Event Hub.

Looking at the Incoming and Outgoing Messages metrics for the Event Hub I have determined that the app can handle about 12k messages per minute per instance.

But I dont understand how to make this into a auto scale setting. Given the above I tried setting it to increase instance count by 1 when incoming messages are more than 10000. However, nothing happens when incoming messages as seen under Metrics for the Event Hubs is about 45000 and my instance count 3. I would expect it to scale up, but it doesnt. Why?

This is what my scale settings look like:

```
{
    "scaleAction": {
        "direction": "Increase",
        "type": "ChangeCount",
        "value": "1",
        "cooldown": "PT5M"
    },
    "metricTrigger": {
        "metricName": "EHINMSGS",
        "metricNamespace": "",
        "metricResourceUri": "my eventhubs",
        "operator": "GreaterThan",
        "statistic": "Average",
        "threshold": 10000,
        "timeAggregation": "Average",
        "timeGrain": "PT1M",
        "timeWindow": "PT5M"
    }
},
{
    "scaleAction": {
        "direction": "Decrease",
        "type": "ChangeCount",
        "value": "1",
        "cooldown": "PT5M"
    },
    "metricTrigger": {
        "metricName": "EHINMSGS",
        "metricNamespace": "",
        "metricResourceUri": "my eventhubs",
        "operator": "LessThan",
        "statistic": "Average",
        "threshold": 1000,
        "timeAggregation": "Average",
        "timeGrain": "PT1M",
        "timeWindow": "PT5M"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if it is an answer but for Azure Function you can have as many function instances running in parallel as many your event hub has partitions. So for example if you event hub has two partitions then only two jobs at the same time are possible.

You can read more here: https://medium.com/@jeffhollan/in-order-event-processing-with-azure-functions-bb661eb55428